# Share tiles and secondary tiles between user accounts in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, powershell, administration

Our Windows 8 Metro application secondary tiles that we need to share between several user profiles on a single PC (tablet).

I was wondering if it is possible to copy secondary tiles (as opposed to normal tiles) between different user accounts? I would rather not have each different user open our app and have to pin X number of tiles per account on each tablet.

I am aware of the `appsFolder.itemdata-ms` file, but my understanding of that is that it is only for the placement of application tiles, not secondary tiles, but I may be wrong.

Perhaps a PowerShell script?

I hope that make sense.

Comment: What exactly are "secondary" tiles?

Comment: @Ramhound: If you have a weather app for example, the primary tile would of course be for the app itself, but you can pin [secondary tiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.startscreen.secondarytile) for your hometown or other cities. Similarly think of additional tiles for a stock app etc.

Comment: @Mark: Isn't pinning (secondary) tiles a user preference? After all if an app installed by another user pinned multiple useless (for me) tiles on my Start Screen, I for sure wouldn't be too happy. Perhaps you can have an option in your app itself for users to click that will programmatically add the extra tiles?

Comment: Yes, in principle, but in this situation it does make sense, but I am looking to automate the process for all the users on a particular PC